# How can i delete content of a page at a particualar time?

Tags: php, date, if-statement

I am trying to delete the contents of a page at a particular time (in my code it is 21:02)
but it does not seem to work, what am I doing wrong?

```
if (date("G") == "21" AND date("i") == "02") {
file_put_contents("comments.html", "");
}
```

Comment: Where is this code executed from?  Is it actually being run at 21:02?

Comment: Yes I tested it at that time and nothing happened.

Comment: Is your server time set correct?

Comment: Is the time on the server the same as on your local client (where the test was made from)?

Comment: What does file_put_contents return?

Comment: Yeah sorry guys I had completely forgot about the time zone my server was in after posting this, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is right, but it will be executed only when your PHP page is invoked via an URL.
To rectify this, create a scheduler task if you are running under a Windows environment, and the job will be `php deleter_page.php`where deleter_page.php contains only this code `file_put_contents("comments.html", "");` and your scheduler task will be programed to run @ your favorite time
tips : add your php installation path to your environment variable `%PATH%`
Hope it helps :)